# passing data between views in express js

Tags: javascript, express

I'm brand new to express and node, so please bear with me :D

i have an index.ejs file. I need to pass a string from my index.ejs file, to my viewActivity.ejs file. That string will then be used  in the javascript portion of my viewActivity.ejs file. I'm not really sure how to go about this though. Is what I want to do even possible? Or do I have to do this via another file and not just directly view to view ?

here is my code. I want to pass the "stringToPass" to another view when a button is clicked.

```
function getPosts() {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Post);
    query.find({
        success: function(results){

            for (var i in results) {
                var title = results[i].get("activityTitle");

                var stringToPass = results[i].id


            }

        }, error: function(error) {
            console.log("Query Error:"+error.message);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: I am an express learner myself and found this interesting. In what scenario do you need the text from view to be passed on to other view? Why wouldn't you consider storing it in a persistent data like DB if you'd share it with other views?

Comment: What I want to do is have a user click on a post, and then the next page (generated via a custom route) displays that individual post and its details. Currently, on the homepage I receive  all my posts from Parse. There may be an easier way to do this I'm not aware of. Im more experienced (but not a pro) in iOS programming, and in iOS this kind of thing is easy--get the id of the object you want to query for, pass that id to the next view via prepareForSegue, and then query for the object with that specific id in the view. I want to do something like that here but am not sure where to start.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken that technique is closely related to delegation. I am not used to iOS programmer myself, but you can attach this `id` of your object in the request that is handled by express in a specific way. Say like if you post an article and attached the `id` of the article on the post request, you'd be able to create a route that detects if the request contains a particular `id` then print out the details of the article.

Comment: yes correct, that is what delegation in iOS is all about. but I just can't figure it out in express.

Answer (score 0):

So far I've learned that express acts as the request handler. E.g.: pass you the file or anything based on the given request.

As soon as the request has been finished being handled, express would not know what the client does with the given result. Hence, once it sent the html file or json file or other request has been responded, all the remaining activities will be handled by a client side script that talks back to the express server in other form of requests. UPDATE: you can make this client side script to extract a DOM element and pass it onto your follow up request (when a user click a submit button, etc) that is handled by a different route.